# Windows 8.1 Slow startup for 16GB RAM

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, performance

I have lenovo Y50 laptop with 16GB RAM and 1TB hdd, When I start system, or start from hybernet mode, It consumes 100% HDD usage for 5-7 minutes, after digging this issue, I got the root cause is that, It is using 8GB of ram for caching, and It coping cache from HDD to RAM at startup, and that is why it is taking 100% HDD utilization.

Is there any other method to improve startup performance or to prevent RAM caching?

**For some days I can't replace my HDD with SSD.**

Comment: I can understand the hibernating issue but I don't see a reason why windows would start slowly with 16GB RAM. If you remove 8GB RAM does windows start up normally?

Comment: what process does it starts at start up (run)msconfig->startup?

Comment: @malakrsnaslava ,It is same even I use Hibernate, as Hibernet will not execute startup applications on boot.

Comment: @Chris.C, sorry, I cant open my laptop because of warranty issue, But this problem is just for startup, after that, it gives high performance. It little bit slower down performance when I try to access hdd only.

Comment: Hibernate or your RAM size are almost certain not the issue. Download procmon from sysinternals and let it monitor the boot process. You can start drawing conclusions from there. If that doesn't give you any pointers, you can use WPA boot recording. Take a look at this [teched](https://www.google.be/search?&q=how+many+coffees+can+you+drink+till+your+pc+starts). It's mostly aimed at group policies but it shows you the WPA way of analyzing a slow boot.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, I agree it is not the issue of RAM, but as it is more ram, so it is taking 8GB for caching, i.e. it is copying 8GB from hdd to RAM, and that is slowing down performance for some time.

Comment: You are talking about the system file cache *(which is a good thing btw)* but that's a (very) low priority thread that shouldn't have any impact on your daily activities. We can theorize this to dead but the only way to be sure is to measure it using for example one of the methods I outlined.

Comment: disable superfetch, but this will **SLOWDOWN** Windows a lot.